# Exchange symmetric keys between client and server using public key

Tags: java, rmi, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric

I wish to exchange symmetric keys between a client and server program running over Java RMI.

My server makes a public key:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = null;
try {
    keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA", "SUN");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
this.priv = pair.getPrivate();
this.pub = pair.getPublic();
```

I send the public key to the client. The client will make a Cipher using the server's public key. I want to use this Cipher to encrypt a SealedObject encapsulating the symmetric key created by the client and send it to the server.

```
//create cipher using server's public key
Cipher cipher = null;
try {
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(serverKey.getAlgorithm(), "SUN");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, serverKey);
} catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when I run the program I have an exception when initializing the cipher:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: No such algorithm: DSA
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:646)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:568)
at Client.main(Client.java:91)
```

I don't understand why I get this NoSuchAlgorithm exception. I don't get this if I make a public key with RSA rather than DSA but RSA gives me:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: 
Data must not be longer than 117 bytes
```

So what am I supposed to use to securely send the sealed object containing my symmetric key?

Comment: Can't you use a standard `SSLServerSocket` instead? TLS does roughly that for you

Comment: I can't. This is an exercise that I need to implement using symmetric keys but first I must securely share the key with the server.

Comment: No such algorithm: DSA is explained here: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/why-dsa-cannot-be-used-for-encryption and the reason for the block size limit error is that RSA is not a regular block cipher either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685470/encrypted-data-size-using-rsa-encryption-rsacryptoserviceprovider or http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/what-type-of-cipher-is-rsa and can therefore only be used within certain limits, e.g. in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange

Comment: Note that this is all pointless unless the client has some way of verifying that the server's public key actually belongs to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @zapl comments, DSA is not an encryption algorithm, and RSA can only encrypt data with size less than the key size minus a small mostly-fixed overhead (11 bytes for PKCS1, which is the default and thus you used; somewhat more for OAEP).

Although not in your posted code, I'll bet the problem is you are trying to seal the `SecretKey` object. Encryption works only on byte (or bit) sequences, represented in Java by byte arrays or sometimes portions of arrays, so `SealedObject` actually serializes the object you give it to bytes and encrypts those bytes, and conversely decrypts those bytes and deserializes them to re-form the object. Java serialization has some overhead, and the various `Key` types in particular are organized in a hierarchy that exacerbates this. For example serializing a `SecretKey` from `KeyGenerator.getInstance("TDES")` is 282 bytes, much too large for RSA-1024 which as your exception says can only be 117 bytes.

Instead **seal only the bytes of the key value** obtained by `SecretKey.getEncoded()`. On the receiver (server) put the bytes back in a `SecretKeySpec` (with the correct algorithm; send that also if not fixed in advance) and you can actually use it as `Key` for symmetric even without running it through a factory (unlike asymmetric keys which have more structure). Even a simple `byte[]` has *some* serialization overhead, but not enough to cause a problem here.